# Why does my function not accept a keymap when called as a variable?

Tags: keymap, functions, variables

I have to remap a lot of keys in existing maps while still remembering the old value of the map. To do that, I wrote some functions that go through lists of keys and lists of keymaps:

```
(defun Daselt/remap (keylist map)
  "A handy function for remapping keys."
  (mapcar (lambda (i)
            (define-key map (kbd (car i)) (nth 1 i))) keylist))

(defun Daselt-basic/remap-map-list (maplist)
  "This remaps the keys of each map according to the corresponding list."
  (mapcar (lambda (i)
            (Daselt/remap (symbol-value (intern (concat "Daselt-basic/" i "-list")))
                          (intern i))) maplist))
```

Now, when I have a list `Daselt-basic/global-map-list` of entries of the form `(list '"key" #'command)`, I can use

```
(Daselt/remap Daselt-basic/global-map-list global-map)
```

and it works. However, if I have a list

```
(defconst Daselt-basic/initial-maps-list
  (list '"global-map")
  "List of maps that are remapped without calling with-eval-after-load.")
```

and I do

```
(Daselt-basic/remap-map-list Daselt/initial-maps-list)
```

I get the error

```
Wrong type argument: keymapp, global-map
```

But `global-map` is a keymap. What is happening?

Comment: You cannot call a function “as a variable”. That’s just nonsense. I have no idea what you’re trying to say, but that’s not it. Also, putting a `'` in front of a quoted string doesn’t do anything. `'"foo"` is just the same as `"foo"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re passing a list of strings to `Daselt-basic/remap-map-list`. It then calls `intern` on each one to convert it to a symbol. It then passes the symbol to `Daselt/remap`, which passes it along to `define-key`. But `define-key` wants a keymap, and a symbol is not a keymap. It might be the name of a variable that holds a keymap, but it isn’t the keymap itself. You need to retrieve the value of the variable with `symbol-value`.

The code would probably be cleaner if the map list contained a list of symbols instead of a list of strings, like this:

```lisp
(defconst Daselt-basic/initial-maps-list
  (list 'global-map)
  "List of maps that are remapped without calling with-eval-after-load.")
```

You would need one less call to `intern`, but you would need to call `symbol-name` on it before you could concatenate up the new symbol name. The real advantage is that your users are presumably already used to naming variables with symbols. It is very unnatural to pass along a list of strings that correspond to variable names, because variable names are symbols.